# How can i style an element without adding a class or id to my HTML?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html-lists

I want to be able to manipulate `<li>F</li>` without adding an id or class?
Is there any way? Is it possible to change the background-color of it just with the HTML code below? Warning: I dont want to change the remaining li

```css
ul li {
  background-color: green; //Doing this, i am changing all of them
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styleA.css">
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
    <li>D</li>
    <li>E</li>
    <li>F</li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could use inline styles like `<li style="color: red;">F</li>` and manipulate that list element without using a class or ID selector.

Comment: Why don't you wan't to change it? You'll have to add a class, id or inline style like `<li style="background-color: red;">A</li>`

Comment: Hi Tanner, but then i would be changing the HTML, and that it is not my goal.

Comment: @AndreProenza Simply adding a `style` attribute to the `<li>` tag, I wouldn't consider to be changing the HTML since the element is only changing in appearance and the DOM structure isn't changing, but if you don't want to use external CSS with a tag selector, class, or ID. Then your only option would be to programmatically restyle the element with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `last-child` or `last-of-type`

```css
ul li:last-child {
  background-color: green;
}

ul li:last-of-type {
  border: dotted  red
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li>D</li>
  <li>E</li>
  <li>F</li>
</ul>
```

---

Other possible solutions:

- `nth-last-child()`/`nth-last-of-type()`
- `nth-child()`/`nth-last-of-type()`

```css
ul li:nth-last-child(1) {
  /* or nth-last-of-type(1) */
  background-color: green;
}


/*not recommended in this scenario if you want more items and always want to target last element*/

ul li:nth-child(6) {
  /* or nth-of-type(6) */
  border: dotted red
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li>D</li>
  <li>E</li>
  <li>F</li>
</ul>
```